# An inverse function for $-\log x/\log (1+x)$

Tags: special-functions, inverse, inverse-function, implicit-function

In the context of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616184/bounds-on-the-root-of-xd1-xd-1) I asked on here a while ago, I came across the problem of inverting the function
$$f(x) = -\frac{\log x}{\log (1 + x)}$$
for positive real $x$. Let $f^{-1}(x)$ denote this branch of the inverse function of $f(x)$.

Alternatively, it can also be defined implicitly as the positive real solution $y$ of the algebraic equation
$$y(1 + y)^x = 1$$

This function $f^{-1}$ is somewhat related to the Lambert $W$ function; for $x\to\infty$, it has the asymptotic expansion
$$f^{-1}(x) = \frac{W(x)}{x} + \frac{W(x)^2}{2 x^2(1 + \frac{1}{W(x)})} + O\left(\frac{W(x)^3}{x^3}\right)$$
but apart from that, I was not able to relate $f^{-1}(x)$ to any other special functions that I am aware of.

I was wondering whether this kind of inverse function was studied in the literature before. If not, I wonder if it may be interesting enough to publish.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT.-Your function $f$ is an open interval bijection, from  $]0,\infty[$ on $]0,-1$[ so $f^{-1}$exists but does not have of it an easy analytical expression and you give an approximation with Lambert $W$ function yourself. You can however draw some points of its graph the following way (maybe you know already this way to draw the inverse of a function):

On the graph of $f(x)$, draw lines $y=-x + a$ for distinct values of $a$ with which you obtain points $(x_0, y_0)$ by intersection of the straight line with the graph of the function. Thus each point $(y_0, x_0)$ is a point of $f^{-1}$.

This is another thing to say that the graph of the inverse of a function is symmetric to the graph of the function with respect to the main diagonal of equation $y = x$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of all of that, and I have of course plotted the function. My question was merely whether this inverse function has been studied by anyone extensively before and/or whether it is of general interest. The Lambert W function, for instance, has its own name and everything. I'm sort of expecting someone to say ‘Oh this is just an instance of the hypergeometric function with this and that parameter and for those, you can find all kinds of results in this book’ or something like that. I'm not very well-versed in the subject of special functions.

Comment: Very well for you.